# spinner1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android

I am not able to understand why i am getting an error here.The error is spinner1 cannot be resolved.Plz help me out fast.I am new to java and android development so explain accordingly.

This is my java code

```
package com.example.dailyexpenses;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {
    String[] Languages = { "Select a Language", "C# Language", "HTML Language",
        "XML Language", "PHP Language" };
        // Declaring the Integer Array with resourse Id's of Images for the Spinners
        Integer[] images = { 0, R.drawable.icon, R.drawable.petrol,
        R.drawable.books, R.drawable.recharge}; 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);

    Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);


    return rootView;
}

 }
```

This is fragment_games.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ff8400" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="choose from the categories below"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <Spinner
  android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
  android:id="@+id/spinner1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:prompt="@string/select">
</Spinner>



 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did my solution/answer worked for you/your app?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call

```
rootView.findViewById
```

since android does not yet to know where to search.

For more explanation:

Probably (not to judge ofc) you are familiar to call `findViewById` in the method `onCreate` of an Activity, but before that you did call `setContentView`. After setting the content by `setContentView` android knows where to search for the id when you call `findViewById`. That is for the case when you are using activity. On the other hand, with fragments it is a different case. You won't be setting the content by `setContentView`, instead you have to prepare a view and return it on `onCreateView` and let the android set the content as it wishes. Be careful, on lines you are calling `findViewById` above there, you haven't return the view yet, so android does not know where to search as you call `findViewById`. So you have to make your searches not on not-set-yet-content, but on the `rootView` you are just about to return. So above the code is the solution to this well described problem.